# What is the relationship between the SOC and the DBMS?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I have read lots of documentation about ArcSDE 9.3 recently but there are still are few things I don´t quite understand because I have not installed the infrastructure myself. If the SOM manages the connections to services and the SOCs host the services, what is the relationship between the SOC and the DBMS?

Is this Workflow correct?

1. Client application requests features from AGS
2. AGS communicates to the SOM that a service has been requested
3. SOM finds the SOC which is runs the service
4. SOC pulls data out of the DBMS and relays the data to SOM and AGS
5. AGS provides visualization and analysis of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the flow, as [documented](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.2/dotnet/manager/administration/how_gis_svr_works.htm), though the point is rendered somewhat moot by the [changes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003p4000000) at 10.1 that eliminated SOM and SOC in favor of the Site architecture. Since all 9.x ArcGIS products are now retired, only 10.0 retains the Server Object Manager/ Server Object Container design.

In either model, the role of the ArcSDE application server is obviated by Direct Connect, adding weight to the worker process (be it SOC or the service processes) to eliminate the database server load of the 'gsrvr' daemon, making the worker process a database client.